# If $X$ is a random variable with $E[X]= \mu, \text {satisfying} P(X \le 0)=0,$ show that $P(X > 2 \mu) \le \frac {1}{2}$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

If $X$ is a random variable with $E[X]= \mu, \text {satisfying } P(X \le 0)=0,$ show that $P(X > 2 \mu) \le \dfrac {1}{2}$

**Attempt:** $P(X > {2\mu}) = \int_{2\mu}^{\infty} f(x) dx \le \int_{0}^{2\mu} f(x) dx +\int_{2\mu}^{\infty} f(x) dx$

Some other results which I could deduce:

$\mu = \int_0^{\infty}x f(x) dx=\int_0^{1} x f(x) dx + \int_1^{\infty} x f(x) dx \ge \int_0^{1} x f(x) dx + \int_1^{\infty}  f(x) dx$

Thr rightmost term is $= \int_0^{2\mu} [x f(x) +f(x) ]dx + \int_{2\mu}^{\infty} [x f(x) +f(x) ]dx$

Could someone please give me a clue on how to move ahead. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have \begin{align}
2\mu I_{X > 2\mu} \le X
\end{align}

Now, take expectation on the both sides and you will get the result.

Note that this is called Markov's inequality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on $P\left(X\leq0\right)=0$ it can be proved that: $$\mathbb{E}\max\left(0,X\right)=\mathbb{E}X=\mu>0$$

Assume that: $$P\left(X>2\mu\right)>\frac{1}{2}$$

Then on base of the following evident inequality: $$\max\left(0,X\right)\geq2\mu\mathbf{1}_{X>2\mu}$$
we find that: $$\mu=\mathbb{E}\max\left(0,X\right)\geq\mathbb{E}2\mu\mathbf{1}_{X>2\mu}=2\mu P\left(X>2\mu\right)>\mu$$
A contradiction is found so our assumption must be wrong.

Conclusion:$$P(X>2\mu)\leq\frac12$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry could you please explain the symbols: $\mu1$. I am a beginner. Thanks again

Comment: Does it mean the first moment $\mu_1$

Comment: No. Here $\mathbf1_A$ stands for the indicator function of set $A$ and $\mathbf1_{X>2\mu}$ abbreviates $\mathbf1_{\{X>2\mu\}}$. So it is the function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if $X(\omega)>2\mu$ and takes value $0$ otherwise. Further $\mu\mathbf1_{X>2\mu}$ must be red as $\mu\cdot\mathbf1_{X>2\mu}$ (i.e. the function is multiplied with constant $\mu$).